# What's the most elegant way to handle the compiler warning about possible loss of data

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings

In our large C++ project, we strive to have no warnings, but people are often lazy about this.  One thing that I am constantly fixing are the warnings from code like this:

```
sizex = sizey = 32 * c_scale;
```

giving

> warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'i16', possible loss of data

Where sizex and sizey are type i16 and c_scale is a double.

So I am constantly changing lines of code like that to something like

```
sizex = sizey = i16(32 * c_scale);
```

to make the warning go away.

I would say that this makes the code less readable, so I'm not happy about it, but it's better than disabling the warning and it's better than having a bunch of warnings obscuring possibly more serious warnings, in my opinion.

Anyone have a more elegant or different way to handle this situation?

Comment: :"*it's better than disabling the warning*" - how so? All you're doing with that cast is telling the compiler to shut up, basically.

Comment: `static_cast` is more idiomatic C++. And no, there aren't any better options than casting to shun this warning. BTW: "but people are often lazy about this" - you can clean up all warnings once and add `-Werror` flag.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I doubt `cl.exe` understands `-Werror`.

Comment: Why do you think it is less readable to explicitly state the intention of discarding some data?

Comment: @melpomene Oops, my bad. Is it `/WX` on MSVC?

Comment: Either you do the cast or you change the warning settings. With those warning settings, you are saying that you *want* to have to do the cast and be warned if you *don't* do it. There's absolutely nothing worng with that - but it is what it is.

Comment: I don't get why the downvotes. This is an important question/issue.

Comment: I'd suggest having a non-standard code named `i16` makes your code inherently unreadable.   Using a conversion of the form `i16(32 * c_scale)` just makes the ugliness a little more obvious.   The most obvious fixes would be to give `i16` a name that actually describes what variables of that type mean in code (e.g. `integral_coordinate`) and try to define a way to do your scaling using some integer arithmetic rather than floating point (e.g. if `c_scale` is rational (a ratio of two integers `numerator/denominator`( then do `sizex = sizey = 32 * numerator/denominator`).

Answer (score 3):

As part of the [CppCoreGuidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines) there is a support library called the [GSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL). They provide a safe way to convert types like this called a *narrow_cast*:

The header for it can be found here: https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/gsl/gsl_util

```
auto sizex = gsl::narrow<unsigned>(32 * c_scale);
```

The idea is that if the resulting type (`unsigned` here) is not large enough (or has a sign violation) an exception will be thrown.

This is a runtime check. If you want to avoid the cost of the runtime check you could construct a similar function that only performs the check during *debug* builds (When `NDEBUG` us not defined) and remove the check for *release* builds.

Comment: Mind you, there's nothing fundamentally wrong with throwing an exception, but it's one half of error handling. The other half is catching the exceptions and doing something with them. And it's the other half which is hard.

Comment: @MSalters I feel these are most useful for *terminal errors* where the values should never be out of range for program correctness. I would never use this for (say) validating user input.

Answer (score 3):

Some useful guidelines for readability and maintainability:

#### Use Standard Types

Imagine I joined your project. I have no idea what an `i16` is, neither do any libraries you link against. But I do know what a `std::int16_t` is (found in `<cstdint>`). So do library writers.

#### Hide Detail behind Abstractions

The operation you describe here is scaling an integer by some factor (say double?). The devil is in the detail. You can't convert a double back into an integer without loss of data so you have to revert to a cast, which looks messy and will make future maintainers wonder what you're up to.

So let's build an abstraction:

```
inline
auto scale_and_round_down(std::int16_t value, double scale) -> std::uint16_t
{
    auto scaled_value = value * scale;  // answer will be a double
    return std::int16_t(value * scale); // round down to nearest int
}
```

now our code becomes:

```
sizex = sizey = scale_and_round_down(32, c_scale);
```

which expresses intent without any doubt. In a release build,  `scale_and_round_down` will be inlined. You will pay no performance cost for abstractions like this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what is your `i16` type, because it is not in the C++11 standard. I am guessing you mean the `ìnt16_t` type from `<cstdint>`, so a signed 16 bits integer, and that your `sizex` and `sizey` are both of `int16_t` type.

Your `c_scale` is some `double`. So probably an IEEE754 64 bits double-precision float. See http://floating-point-gui.de/ for more. It has a 53 bits mantissa.

How can you expect that 53 bits fit *without loss* (in *all* cases) in 16 bits? The [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) applies and tells you immediately that, since 2<sup>53</sup> is bigger than 2<sup>16</sup>, it is not the case.

The compiler is right to give you some warning. Indeed, you could *explicit* some cast to avoid that warning

And by *expliciting* the cast, you just tell your reader that you are aware of that. Probably, the generated machine code won't change at all with or without the cast.

Maybe your particular compiler might have some other ways to disable that warning (perhaps some `#pragma`)

You could consider using some more sophisticated static analysis technology (maybe [Frama-Clang](https://frama-c.com/frama-clang.html)) to make a more semantical analysis and prove you that the cast don't leak precision. Beware, such tools could be difficult to master!

BTW, the C++ standard don't tell much about warnings in general (they are a "quality of implementation" thing). You can decide to ignore them (but in practice you should not).

Comment: _"You can decide to ignore them."_ But don't!